# Continuous and differentiable function in Rolle's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

When we state Rolle's theorem, we say that the function is continuous on a closed interval and differentiable in an open interval. Why we do not assume differentiability on the closed interval?

Answer (score 3):

Because differentiation is not well defined on a closed interval. In fact we need to know what happen on the right and on the left of all point of the interval.

Hence in order to prove that a continuous function admits maximum or minimum we do not need the differentiability at the extreme points of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Also: because even if we define differentiability in the border points as existence of lateral derivatives, in the *proof* of the theorem only derivatives in the interior are required.
Sketch of proof:

If $f$ is constant, the conclusion is trivial.

If $f$ isn't constant, max or min are reached in the *interior* of the interval and this *global* max/min is also *local* max/min. Then, derivative in this point is zero.